# Express 3, Apache proxies, and basepath

Tags: node.js, express, mod-proxy, node.js-connect

I have an older Express 2.5.9 app that I'm bringing up-to-date with Express 3.4.x. In production, the app is proxied by Apache using a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/app/(.*)$ http://nodeserver.example.com:3000/$1 [P,L]
RewriteRule ^/path/to/app$ /path/to/app/ [R,L]
```

So, in production, `http://example.com/path/to/app/foo` is proxied to `http://nodeserver.example.com:3000/foo`, and Express handles the /foo route normally.

In Express 2.x, I used the `basepath` setting so that redirects were handled properly in production (e.g. if I needed to redirect to `/login`, the `basepath` setting, set to `/path/to/app` would actually redirect to `/path/to/app/login`. `basepath` was not set in development (e.g. accessing the app at `http://localhost:3000`).

`basepath` has been removed in Express 3, so that setting no longer works, and neither do my redirects (e.g. if I go to `http://example.com/path/to/app/admin`, that route has middleware that redirects to `/login`, which ends up being redirected to `http://example.com/login`).

I could re-write my redirects from

```
res.redirect('/login')
```

to

```
var redirectUrl = config.basepath ? config.basepath + '/login' : '/login'
res.redirect(redirectUrl)
```

but that seems inelegant.

I've considered the mounting approach, but it seems a bit overkill for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Express API doc](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) you should maybe just turn

```
res.redirect('/login')
```

to

```
res.redirect('login')
```

and do the mounting-approach, because that seems to be the right way of doing it since version 3.